# Orthogonal Initialization for the Embedding Layer in Keras/TensorFlow

Tags: keras, svd, word-embedding

I am trying to initialize an embedding layer in Keras so that cosine similarity among all word vectors is close to zero.

When setting embeddings_initializer to Orthogonal(), on the vocab size of 2M and dim=300, error "ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB." is raised.

When trying to initialize manually with

```
r = np.random.randn(len(voc),300); 
vectors, s, v = np.linalg.svd(r, full_matrices=False)
```

the average similarity is 0 but there are many vectors with similarity around 0.25.

Is there any efficient way to initialize embeddings weights so that cosine similarity between any pair of word vectors is close to zero?